# Python: Unsupported operand while adding 2 functions output in python?

Tags: python

I am using python 3.8.8 and while running a simple program of Fibonacci it is **giving me an error** i.e. `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`

```
def fibo(n):
if n <= 1:
    print("Hey! Please enter value greater than 1")
else:
    return((fibo(n-1)) + fibo(n-2))

nterms = 10
res = fibo(nterms)
print(res)
```

Comment: You are getting that error because the function doesn't return anything for the condition `n<=1`. Just replace that print statement with `return n`.

Comment: not at all @Sören

Comment: Note that, via the recursion, `fibo` will eventually be called with `n` equal to 1.  In which case, your error message will print and the function will exit with no `return` statement.  In Python, if a function exits with no `return` statement, then `None` is implicitly returned.

Comment: Please don't alter your code's behavior after posting it.  That makes it difficult for us to address any issues.

Comment: Notice that at no time does your code ever return a number. Ask yourself how addition could possibly work.

Comment: This code cannot produce the claimed result.  Please post the real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `return n` to your code

```py
def fib(n):
    if n<=1:
        return n 
    else:
        return(fib(n-1) + fib(n-2))

for i in range(10):
    print(f"fib({i}) = " + str(fib(i)))
```

gives

```
fib(0) = 0
fib(1) = 1
fib(2) = 1
fib(3) = 2
fib(4) = 3
fib(5) = 5
fib(6) = 8
fib(7) = 13
fib(8) = 21
fib(9) = 34
```